# Batch Job on Windows Server 2012 Access denied

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012, vtiger

The batch file is used to execute php files.

Unfortunately whenever i execute the batch file. Access denied error is appear.

below is the source code of my batch file.

> set VTIGERCRM_ROOTDIR="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\vtigercrm600\apache\htdocs\vtigerCRM" set PHP_EXE="C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\vtigercrm600\php\php.exe"
>
> cd /D %VTIGERCRM_ROOTDIR%
>
> %PHP_EXE% -f vtigercron.php
>
> pause

Comment: so, determine what the permissions problem is. We can't!

Comment: Are you running the batch file as administrator?

Comment: sorry guys..the problem is not from the batch job..but the problem of my php code..the php page itself that return access denied..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem of the php file itself. Not related to windows server security setting.

Sorry for the trouble.

Thank you.